# Command to use with easy way the insert of R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe loaded successfully in `R`.

I would like to give the data of df to someone else to use them with quick and easy way without need to load again the file into a df.

Which is the command to give the whole data of df (not the str())

Comment: Welcome to CV! Programming questions are generally off-topic here, but you may have more luck on stack overflow.

Comment: @SeanEaster thank you. I though it wasn't exactly a programming question, that's the reason I made it here but I go to stackoverflow. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a stackexchange question. But [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) is an answer.

You can save the object.

```
mydata <- cars
save(mydata, file = "cars_data")
```

This code saves my data frame in file called "cars_data". You can now email this, send this file to anyone who can load the data using

```
load("cars_data")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should save the workspace, that would create a file with the extension .RData that has all your objects. send the file to the other person, once they'll open it, that would load all the objects
(yet this is not a question for Cross Validate)

command to save the workspace

```
save.image("path/file.RData")
```

command to load the workspace

```
load("path/file.RData")
```